# how can I embeed dailymotion player in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I want to add dailymotion player in my react class based component
but i find this error

first I have declare this variable

```js
  componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log(
      "daily motion================================================================================================================================================================================"
    );
    this.setState({ test: true });
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src ="https://geo.dailymotion.com/player";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    this.playerLoad()

  };

  playerLoad = () => {
    console.log("daily motion player load ");
    this.player = window.dailymotion
      .createPlayer("my-dailymotion-player", {
        video: "x84sh87",
      })
      .then((player) => console.log(player))
      .catch((e) => console.error(e));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking.

```
<script src="https://geo.dailymotion.com/libs/player/x5poh.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

```
// React Hook
const useEffect = React.useEffect;

const Player = (props) => {
  // dynamic random target id
  const targetId = "playerDiv-"+ Math.floor(Math.random() * 99);
  
  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    dailymotion
    .createPlayer(targetId, {
      video: props["data-video"],
      player: props["data-playerid"]
    })
    .then((player) => console.log(player))
    .catch((e) => console.error(e));
  }, []);
  
  
  return <div id={targetId}></div>
};

const App = () => {
  return (
      <>
        <Player 
          data-playerid="x5poh"
          data-video="x84sh87"
        />
        <br/>
        <Player 
          data-playerid="xow6u"
          data-video="x84sh87"
        />
      </>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

source:
https://codepen.io/team/dailymotion-developer/pen/bGZqvwo?editors=1010

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).